# Polar form of Complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm doing some work with complex numbers and I've come across this exercise in the "Polar form" section.

$$(1/2+i(\sqrt{3}/2))^{100}$$

Of course this exercise is manageable with the help of Pascal's triangle and numerous hours of calculating, but I assume there's a much simpler solution.

The result should be: $$-(1/2)-i(\sqrt{3}/2)$$

I'm appreciative with any possible help.

Thanks,

Bobby

Comment: Take the section name as a hint and start by rewriting $\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2 i$ into polar form.

Comment: and then use $(e^{i\theta})^n=e^{i\theta n}$

Comment: Alright, with my calculations, (not messing with ^100) I get $e^{i\pi/3}$ so I should get something like $e^{i\pi/3*100}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2=R(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$  where $R\ge 0$

Equating the real & the imaginary part, $R\cos\theta=\frac12$ and $\frac{\sqrt3}2=R\sin\theta$

Squaring & adding we get, $R^2=1\implies R=1$

On division, $\tan\theta=\sqrt 3$ so that $\theta=\frac \pi3$ as both $\sin\theta,\cos\theta>0$

So, $\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2=\cos\frac \pi3+i\sin\frac \pi3$

Using [de Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)/[identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/deMoivresIdentity.html), $(\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2)^3=(\cos\frac \pi3+i\sin\frac \pi3)^3=\cos\pi+i\sin\pi=-1$

Hence, $(\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2)^{100}=\{(\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2)^3\}^{33}(\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2)=(-1)^{33}(\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2)=-(\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2)$

Answer (score 3):

The Euler's formula says that
$$
e^{i\phi}=\cos(\phi)+i\sin(\phi)
$$
So we get that
$$
\frac{1+i\sqrt3}{2}=e^{i\pi/3}
$$
So raising both sides to the power $100$, remembering $e^{i2\pi}=1$, yields
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1+i\sqrt3}{2}\right)^{100}
&=e^{i\pi100/3}\\
&=e^{i\pi4/3}\\
&=e^{i\pi}\frac{1+i\sqrt3}{2}\\
&=-\frac{1+i\sqrt3}{2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: How did you get $e^{i\pi100/3}$ to $e^{i\pi4/3}$

Comment: @Rob $(e^{i2\pi})^{16}\times e^{i\pi\frac43}$