# From Complex number to polar

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

I have to calculate $(3 + 3i)^{829}$

What I did:

$$|3 + 3i| = \sqrt{3^2 + 3^2} = \sqrt{9 + 9}=\sqrt{18}$$

The argument of $3 + 3i$ is  $45º$.

Comment: Most of your equations don't make sense. First make sure you are really writing equations (it doesn't look like you really are) when you write something as an equation, and then format it so we can actually see the math notation correctly, using http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Also try to be more specific about what you did. We don't know what you multiplied by $829$ or what math error you got when you tried it.

Comment: $(3 + 3i)${^8}{^2}{^9} what does it mean?
Would you like $(3 + 3i)^{829}$ or $(((3 + 3i)^{8})^2)^9$?

Comment: @RobertZ I edited it

Comment: Now the equations are readable and true, well done! I simplified one of the formats, hoping it is still what you meant.

Comment: But so far everything looks good with your calculations, so what was the difficulty?

Comment: Yes, but I dont know how to calculate this raised to 829

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is in the title: you need to write the number in polar form:
$$x+\mathrm i y = r(\cos\theta+\mathrm i \sin\theta)$$
where $r$ is the modulus of $x+\mathrm i y$ and $\theta$ is the argument.

In your case, you have $x + \mathrm i y = 3 + 3\mathrm i$.

The modulus is given by $\left|3+3\mathrm i\right|=\sqrt{3^2+3^2}=3\sqrt{2}$.

Since $3+3\mathrm i$ lies on the line $y=x$, and is in the upper-right quadrant. The argument is given by $\arg(3+3\mathrm i)=\frac{1}{4}\pi$.

That means that $r=3\sqrt{2}$ and $\theta=\frac{1}{4}\pi$, and hence
$$3+3\mathrm i = 3\sqrt{2}\left(\cos(\tfrac{1}{4}\pi)+\mathrm i \sin(\tfrac{1}{4}\pi)\right)$$

[De Moivre's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) tells is that $(\cos \theta + \mathrm i \sin \theta)^n = \cos (n\theta) + \mathrm i \sin (n\theta)$.

It follows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
(3+3\mathrm i)^{829} &=& (3\sqrt 2)^{829}\left(\cos(\tfrac{829}{4}\pi)+\mathrm i \sin(\tfrac{829}{4}\pi)\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

The sine and cosine functions are $2\pi$-periodic, i.e. they repeat every $2\pi$ and so $\sin(x+2\pi)\equiv \sin x$ just like $\cos(x+2\pi) \equiv \cos x$ for all real $x$. We can subtract multiples of $2\pi=\frac{8}{4}\pi$ from $\frac{829}{4}\pi$ without changing the values of sine and cosine.

Since $829 = 4 \times 206 + 5$ it follows that $\frac{829}{4} = 206 + \frac{5}{4}$ and hence $\frac{829}{4}\pi = 206\pi + \frac{5}{4}\pi$.

Given that sine and cosine are $2\pi$ periodic:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos(\tfrac{829}{4}\pi) &=& \cos(206\pi + \tfrac{5}{4}\pi) \\ \\
&=& \cos(\tfrac{5}{4}\pi) \\ \\
\sin(\tfrac{829}{4}\pi) &=& \sin(206\pi + \tfrac{5}{4}\pi) \\ \\
&=& \sin(\tfrac{5}{4}\pi)
\end{eqnarray*}

It follows that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(3\sqrt 2)^{829}\left(\cos(\tfrac{829}{4}\pi)+\mathrm i \sin(\tfrac{829}{4}\pi)\right) &=& (3\sqrt 2)^{829}\left(\cos(\tfrac{5}{4}\pi)+\mathrm i \sin(\tfrac{5}{4}\pi)\right) \\ \\
&=& (3\sqrt 2)^{829}\left(-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\,\mathrm i \right) \\ \\
&=& -3^{829}\times 2^{414} \times (1+\mathrm i)
\end{eqnarray*}

This number is massive and shouldn't be written down.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply , You've helped me a lot. Is it advisable to put the result ? Or would it be more correct to leave it ?

Comment: If the question was to compute $(3+3\mathrm i)^{829}$ then that is the answer. Perhaps they wanted the argument? In that case, it would be the argument of $-(1+\mathrm i)$ which is $-\frac{3}{4}\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $3+3i=3(1+i)=3\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}=\sqrt{18}e^{i\pi/4}$.  Hence
$$(3+3i)^{829}=18^{829/2}\cdot e^{i\pi/4\cdot 829}=
18^{829/2}\cdot e^{i\pi/4\cdot (103\cdot 8+5)}=
18^{829/2}\cdot e^{i5\pi/4}$$
because $829=103\cdot 8+5$ and $(e^{i\pi/4})^8=e^{8i\pi/4}=e^{2\pi i}=1$.

P.S. Take a look to this similar exercise: [Polar form of Complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252338/polar-form-of-complex-numbers?rq=1)

Comment: Nice answer but I think im a bit lost, you use a theory to calculate it?

Comment: So what is the argument of $(3+3i)^{829}$?

Comment: Yes , I would like to know how to calculate it raised to 829

Comment: Do you know how to use the polar form? What happens when you multiply two complex numbers in polar form?

Comment: I think something escapes me. I have not used the polar way to get 18 ? or I have to keep using it ?

Comment: When you take a $n$-power in polar form you have to raise the modulus to $n$ and multiply the argument by $n$. Moreover in the argument you can throw away the integer multiples of $2\pi$ (i.e. $360º$)